# C++ floats being converted to ints

Tags: c++, floating-point

I have the following function that should return an average of **l1**- **l7**. However, it seems to only return an integer. Why is it doing this, and how do I make it return a float rounded to 2 decimal places?

Snippet:

```
int lab_avg(int l1,int l2,int l3,int l4,int l5,int l6,int l7) {
    float ttl;
    ttl = l1 + l2 +l3 +l4 +l5 +l6 +l7;
    return ttl / 7.0; 
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because your function's return type is an `int`. Change it to `float` and it'll work fine.

Also, if you just want to print 2 decimal places, use an appropriate format in your output function. You don't need to do anything with the float itself:

```
printf("%.2f", some_value);
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the function return type is `int`.
So the result `ttl/7.0` which will be a `float` will be cast to an `int` and then returned.

Change the return type to `float` to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

the return type of your function should be float instead of int.

Answer (score 3):

As others pointed out, changing the return type to `float` instead of `int` will yield a `float` value..

To set the 2 digits precision  [`setprecision ( int n )`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/) , will be helpful...

Also for precision, you can use [`ios_base::precision`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/precision/)...

Answer (score 0):

```
float ttl;
float lab_avg(int l1,int l2,int l3,int l4,int l5,int l6,int l7) 
 {

 ttl = l1 + l2 +l3 +l4 +l5 +l6 +l7;
 return (ttl/7); 
 }

int main()
 {
  lab_avg(11,12,13,14,15,16,17);
   printf("%.2f", ttl);
  return 0;
}
```